# soapui testrunner -A equivalent to java class SoapUITestCaseRunner?

Tags: java, soapui

what is the equivalent method name for testrunner -A command line option?
https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html

```
    SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
    runner.setProjectFile("my_project.xml);
    runner.setExportAll(true);
    runner.run();
```

when i run, it does not organize files with test results into directories and subdirectories

Comment: It is the same `runner.setExportAll(true)`

Comment: @Rao, No it doesn't. When i run runner.setExportAll(true), it's export with format `ProjectName_TestSuite_TestCase_TestStep-XX.txt`

`testrunner -A` will export to format
    Directory
        -----SubDir
            ----TestCase.txt

Comment: Could not get you which way you want?

Comment: @Rao i want to achieve this `A : Turns on exporting of all results using folders instead of long` - seems `setExportAll(true)` equivalent to `a : Turns on exporting of all test results, not only errors`.